# Creating a folder structure and copy files into specific folders

Tags: applescript

I work in a design agency and am trying to create an applescript that creates a folder structure and then afterwards copies files into specified folders that it creates.

I am a newbie to applescript and after hours of trawling the internet I have managed to create the bit that creates the folders. This allows me to create folders with specific job numbers then choose where to save it. This all works well. All I want to do now is to copy a couple of documents into folders that it creates.

This is what I have so far:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate

    set jobNum to text returned of (display dialog "Enter a job number:" default answer "")
    set jobName to text returned of (display dialog "Enter a job name:" default answer "")
    set folderpath to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Select client folder")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Reference") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Briefs")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Reference") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Copy")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Reference") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Supplied")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Assets")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Old")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Final_Artwork")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Assets") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Purchased_Images")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Assets") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Non_Purchased_Images")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_In_Situ") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_JPG's")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_In_Situ") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_PSD's")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Artwork_&_Design") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Id")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Artwork_&_Design") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Ai")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Artwork_&_Design") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_PS") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_PSDs")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Artwork_&_Design") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_PS") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_JPGs")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Artwork_&_Design") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Presentation_Boards")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_C4D") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Assets")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_C4D") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Renders")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_C4D") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Visuals")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Creative") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Mac_Scamps")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Creative") & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_Scamps")
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of folderpath & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_" & jobName) & "/" & quoted form of (jobNum & "_For_Client")


end tell
```

E.g. I want to copy an InDesign file into the "presentation boards" folder and copy a pdf into the reference file which would then open once the applescript had finished.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Don't use a do shell script inside a tell application block, unless you're targeting the current application constant. It violates the scripting addition security and will sometimes throws errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [move a file in finder with applescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058061/move-a-file-in-finder-with-applescript)

Answer (score 0):

You can set all the folders as variables and feed it an input folder to move files and sort them. Can't get too specific or you will run into an issue of it won't work for other jobs. I would go like this.

```
    set jobNum to text returned of (display dialog "Enter a job number:" default answer "")
        set jobName to text returned of (display dialog "Enter a job name:" default answer "")
        set folderpath to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Select client folder")
    set InputFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Select client folder") as alias

    tell application "Finder"
    set FileList to get every item of folder InputFolder

    set FolderVariable to make new folder at Desination with properties{Name:"folderName" & jobName"}
 set FolderVariable2 to make new folder at Desination with properties{Name:"folderName" & jobName"}

    repeat with CurrentFile in FileList
    if (name of CurrentFile) contains "SomeIdentifier" then
    move file CurrentFile to folder FolderVariable
else if (name of CurrentFile) contains "SomeotherIdentifier" then
 move file CurrentFile to folder FolderVariable2 
    end if
    end tell
```

Add more ifs if you have different identifiers