# Moving a File with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

Today is my first day of even knowing AppleScript exists so I apologize if this is a stupid question. I've searched and can't find the answer on how to simply move a file with AppleScript

All I need to do is move a file from ~/Downloads/blank.potx to ~/Library/Application Support/Office/User Templates/My Templates

This is what I have in AppleScript right now:

```
tell application "Finder"
     move "~/Downloads/blank.potx" to "~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/User Templates/My Templates/blank.potx"
end tell
```

When I run this it gives me an error:

```
error "Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000
```

Again, first day using AppleScript and I'm lost.  Any help you can provide would be awesome.

If there's a better way to do this please let me know as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Search is your friend. You can easily find the syntax on stack overflow. Such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058061/move-a-file-in-finder-with-applescript):

```
tell application "Finder"
    move POSIX file "/Users/xx/Documents/img.jpg" to POSIX file "/Users/xx/Documents/State" with replacing
end tell
```

If you're gonna use Posix file paths, you need to indicate so, and you need to name the string as a file.

Comment: This (official) document outlines the various (and many) kinds of file reference available in AppleScript. It ought to be easy, but it isn't. Different commands require different file reference forms. Some (decently built) ones accept all kinds, but you'll still have to follow the various conventions to distinguish one from another.

https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-6681