# Applescript Error - Can't Get every file of ... folder?

Tags: applescript

I have a script that someone else wrote.  It works on his computer but not mine.

Originally it said `"as alias"`, but I kept getting an error message as follows:

> `"Can’t make file "Macintosh HD:Users:williamsato:Desktop:Photobooth:CurrentSession" into type alias."`

So I changed `alias` to `string`, following a suggestion made in another post.

Now I don't get that error message, but I do get a new one as shown below:

> `"Can’t get every file of "Macintosh HD:Users:williamsato:Desktop:PhotoBooth:CurrentSession"."`

And it highlights the line *"move files of SourceFolder to DestinationFolder with replacing"*

Not sure what is going wrong.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set SourceFolder to POSIX file "/Users:/williamsato/Desktop/Photobooth/CurrentSession" as string
    set DestinationFolder to POSIX file "/Users/williamsato/Desktop/Photobooth/PreviousSessions" as string

    tell application "Finder"
        move files of SourceFolder to DestinationFolder with replacing
    end tell
    (* Clear Large Type *)
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "a" using command down
end run
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [move a file in finder with applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058061/move-a-file-in-finder-with-applescript)

Comment: 1. How is this script being run? 2. As coded, It needs to be `as alias` 3. There a `:` that should not be in `/Users:/`. 4. What do you expect out of `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "a" using command down`? I see no value in it based on the code you've shown!

Answer (score 0):

Here are three different way of forming the `SourceFolder` and `DestinationFolder` *variables* and moving the files:

```
set SourceFolder to (path to desktop folder as string) & "Photobooth:CurrentSession:" as alias
set DestinationFolder to (path to desktop folder as string) & "Photobooth:PreviousSessions:" as alias

tell application "Finder" to move files of SourceFolder to DestinationFolder with replacing
```

---

```
set SourceFolder to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:williamsato:Desktop:Photobooth:CurrentSession:"
set DestinationFolder to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:williamsato:Desktop:Photobooth:PreviousSessions:"

tell application "Finder" to move files of SourceFolder to DestinationFolder with replacing
```

---

```
set SourceFolder to POSIX file "/Users/williamsato/Desktop/Photobooth/CurrentSession" as alias
set DestinationFolder to POSIX file "/Users/williamsato/Desktop/Photobooth/PreviousSessions" as alias

tell application "Finder" to move files of SourceFolder to DestinationFolder with replacing
```

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

Comment: Thank you for providing those lines of code.  I copied and pasted each of the lines of code that you provided into automator, and I got this error for all 3: "The run handler is specified more than once, or there were top-level commands in addition to the run handler."

p.s. this is a different error message, after I upgraded to Catalina, than what I received before.

Comment: @William, each of the three example are meant to be used by themselves, not all together! Also, if conditions have changed from your original posting then you should edit the question or if appropriate ask a different question. Additionally, for testing purposes these examples work without issue for me when obviously replacing your name with mine for the later two examples. You never responded to the questions I asked in the comment to your OP and without seeing your actual workflow and all code being run there is nothing else I can do for you, sorry.